# Can't save to a JSON file on Win7 from an AIR app

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm writing an AIR app that reads from, and writes to a local JSON file. I'm using the File and FileStream classes. It works perfectly on Mac, but on Win7 it's not saving. Does anyone know of any platform-specific issues or tips for the .writeUTFBytes() method?

```
file = new File(itemBase + "/manifest.json");
fileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.UPDATE);
fileStream.writeUTFBytes(json);
```

Thanks,
Wayne

Comment: Are you getting any specific error messages? File permissions are the first thing that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 2):

On windows7 you will generally not have write permission to the "program files"-folder. You should probably set up a folder under user documents or something like that.

This might come in handy:
(from: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html)

- File.applicationStorageDirectory—a storage directory unique to each
  installed AIR application
- File.applicationDirectory—the read-only directory where the application is installed (along with any installed assets)
- File.desktopDirectory—the user's desktop directory
- File.documentsDirectory—the user's documents directory
- File.userDirectory—the user directory